# Menu link from one project to another. Web Forms to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a solution of 10 projects.

1 is a application that is the main one. Then 8 are just classes.

The main application is using classic ASP and Web Forms which I have no clue on how to use. I am more familiar with MVC.

So I created a new project (MVC) for basic administration of the site. Users add/edit/delete, that kind of stuff.

Currently working locally using IIS Express in VS 2017.

My goal is to make a menu item in the main application that will redirect to the new MVC admin project. With working locally I can get this to work by setting different ports in the project settings but how do I get this to work without changing ports because when I deploy it then ports won't matter. I think, still new to this.

Any idea how I get the user to browse from a classic ASP application to an MVC application in the same solution? I have the references and dependencies already set.

** Added

Main Project - http://localhost:12345/

Start Page - Index.aspx

Secondary Project - http://localhost:54321/

Start Page - Home/Index/

If I change secondary project to something like http://localhost:12345/admin/ then create a virtual directory it seems to work but I get a Dev Express error. Dev Express has NOTHING to do with the secondary project but it is in the main project.

Comment: When you deploy the applications, what are their respective URLs?  Why can't you make a link to the target URL?

Comment: In addition to @David's comment, the only complication I can see is if you need to keep the same session between the applications. Is this the case?

Comment: I can't deploy the application yet. If I could then I could probably figure this all out.

Currently I can only work within VS 2017 and running locally using IIS Express. This is probably why I can't see the solution to this issue.

I don't really need to worry about sessions, cookies, or anything like that. I can just reauthentic the user if needed. The projects really only need to pass 1 thing to each other and that is the currently logged in user.

Main project starts at index.aspx
Second project is MVC so currently using /Home/Index/

Comment: @AaronN: Well, any way you look at it, in order to make a link that goes to a web address you'll need to know what that web address *is*.  Once you know that, you can make the link.  For development purposes you can create any placeholder link you like.  I imagine this link would likely be driven by a config value which would (could) vary by deployed environment.

Comment: @David I know the root URL to what it will be. My issue is that I am trying to get to get it work locally which might not work. Are you saying that if I am on a web form project and enter an MVC address in the URL after root /Home/Index/ it will know to go to that specific project and not the main one?

Comment: @AaronN: I'm saying that if you link to a URL then the browser will know to go to that URL.  Of course, that URL needs to be correct and valid or you'll likely get a 404 or some other error.  If these are separate projects then they are separate application instances, they don't inherently know anything about each other.  Don't think about this in terms of projects in a solution.  That's a development concept, not a deployment concept.  Think about this in terms of application instances.  You need to know the URL of the instance you want to link to in order to link to it.

Comment: @David Thanks. Think I understand this a little better. When I finally get to deploy this using IIS I can set each application up to a different URL, right? So main project will be www.site.com and new admin project can be set to www.site.com/admin/ ? Then when the user goes to /admin/ IIS will run the admin project? This is how I see it happening I just can't test the theory yet. My goal is to try to test this all locally using IIS Express and VS 2017. But I am guessing I can't configure IIS Express to do this and need IIS.